# Execute rename files with a bat file - Invalid FORFILES option

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to rename a couple of files in a path adding at the end just a kind of timestamp.

I have created the script below based on a quick research using .bat files:

```
@ECHO off
set Time="%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%"
set Time=%Time: =%
Forfiles /P "C:\Batches\ftp_outputfiles\" /M *.txt /C "cmd /c ren @file @fname-%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%%Time%.txt"
```

However, the system returns the message :

ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '@file' .
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage

I appreciate if someone of you could guide me in this issue. thanks

Comment: Remove the trailing backslash from the path.

Comment: If `@file` outputs as `"filename.ext"` then `@fname-` outputs as `"filename"-` and double quotes are not allowed characters in file names.

Comment: @Compo - There are multiple problems, including a problem with quotes. But not in the way you think. REN (and other commands) allow quotes within paths, and they get stripped. So `ren file.txt "this "and" that.txt"` results in a file named `this and that.txt`. However, you do have to worry about which characters are quoted with respect to token delimiters and poison characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugh. You have compounding problems that make the bug tricky to trace.

Before I explain how your code is failing, I will give you a much simpler and faster solution using FOR instead of FORFILES.

I also use WMIC to get your timestamp in a reliable way instead of manipulating `%DATE%` and `%TIME%`, which can fail depending on the computer configuration. My code produces a timestamp as `YYMMDDhhmm`, which is what I believe you were striving for.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "ts="
for /f "skip=1" %%A in ('wmic os get localDateTime') do if not defined ts set "ts=%%A"
for %%F in ("C:\Batches\ftp_outputfiles\*.txt") do ren %%F "%%~nF-%ts:~0,12%.txt"
```

OK - now to list the many problems in your original code, and the effect they have.

1) You should never define your own TIME variable, as that prevents subsequent code from accessing the dynamic TIME value.

2) You forgot to use SETLOCAL at the top, so your TIME definition persists after the script terminates. That means subsequent runs no longer get the dynamic TIME value, but instead take substrings of the result from the prior run.

3) Not really a bug, but you don't need the quotes in the variable value. Better to use `set "var=someValue"` instead of `set var="someValue"`. The former quotes the expression from a parsing standpoint, but the quotes are not included in the assignment. The latter form includes the quotes in the value.

4) And the final bug that leads to your unexpected error message - the FORFILES command treats `\"` as an escaped quote, so the \P value is much longer than you think!

Your code (abbreviated) is

```
Forfiles /P "C:\Batches\ftp_outputfiles\" /M *.txt /C "cmd /c ren @file @fname-...txt"
```

The /P option expects a value which is parsed as:
`"C:\Batches\ftp_outputfiles\" /M *.txt /C "cmd`

The FORFILES argument parser preserves everything between quotes as a single argument, but the `\"` is escaped, so it keeps on going until the next quote. There is no token delimiter after the next `"`, so `cmd` is included in the value as well.

The next token is `/c` which is a valid option that expects a value. So the `ren` is treated as the command value.

The next token is `@FILE` which is not a valid option. Hence the `ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '@file'.` error message.

The simple way to avoid this nasty parsing issue is to drop the trailing `\` from the path so the argument ends at the quote as desired:

```
forfiles /P "C:\Batches\ftp_outputfiles" /M ....
```

Another option is to drop the quotes, but that only works because your path does not have characters like spaces that need quotes.

```
forfiles /P C:\Batches\ftp_outputfiles\ /M ....
```

Comment: Man what an outstanding explanation thanks a lot , marked as done :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
@ECHO off
set Time="%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%"
set Time=%Time: =%
Forfiles /P C:\Batches\ftp_outputfiles\ /M *.txt /C "cmd /c rename @file @fname1-%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%%Time%.txt"
```

I hope I've helped.

Comment: See `help ren` - using the short or long name isn't the problem